# AngularJS Error injector send me to https://code.angularjs.org/

Tags: angularjs

I am working with angularjs and gulp to update when I change something. But everytime I have a error I get a link to https://code.angularjs.org/ where the error is explained.

Is there a way to display this directly in the console instead of clicking everytime on the url to find out what the error is.
Have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01DPB.png) in the console.

Comment: Are you including minified version of AngularJS? Can you try using uncompressed version of AngularJs and see if error shows on console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gulp setup should allow you to test your code un-minified, which will give you easier-to-understand errors. The provider error you're getting sounds like it's coming from your config block in app.js - maybe you're specifying a 'session' argument in config erroneously? Or perhaps you're not using injection - which will cause minified code to error out. Example with injection:

```
.config(['$httpProvider',
   function appConfig($httpProvider) {
      ...
   }
])
```

Without injection this will fail when you minify:

```
.config(
   function appConfig($httpProvider) {
      ...
   }
)
```